# setting a UILabel alpha level in cocoa-touch

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm having a little late night problem trying to get a `UILabel`'s alpha changed.
I can do

```
theLabel.alpha = 0.0
```

and it works fine.  But when I want to change it a bit more remotely like

```
[[self.uploadDisplayLabels objectAtIndex:i] setAlphaValue: 0.0];
```

I get no end of crashes. I have tried `setAlpha` and also `alpha` but none of them work

Any suggestions?

Comment: We will need more code. Or maybe a stack dump. Then we can help.

Comment: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILabel setAlphaValue:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x183a10' - is what is coming up.

Comment: LATE NIGHT STUPIDITY - JUST SOME TYPOS - SORRY

Answer (score 2):

`setAlpha:` is definitely correct. What error do you get when you use that?